# Why do I get a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching found exception when I see a wildcard entry

Tags: java, ssl, artifactory, ivy

I'm getting the following SSL error when trying to resolve packages from atlassian's artifactory repo via ivy.

[ivy:retrieve]  Server access error at url https://packages.atlassian.com/repository/public/net/minidev/json-smart/ (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching packages.atlassian.com found.)

However, when I view the certificate in Chrome or Firefox, it appears valid. The Subject Alternative Name extension has the following values.

```
Not Critical
DNS Name: *.atlassian.com
DNS Name: atlassian.com
```

Is this an error on my side or atlassian's? How would I go about solving it, preferably without disabling any SSL security?

Comment: The certificate is indeed valid for `packages.atlassian.com` as it includes the wildcard under the domain. So you need to make sure that "ivy" sees that exact same certificate (particularly in enterprise settings there are certificates hijacking politics), and if so it seems to be a bug on that part.

Comment: My guess is that this has something to do with SNI. When doing a TLS connection without SNI one gets the certificate for `*.services.atlassian.com`, only with SNI set to `packages.atlassian.com` one gets the certificate for `*.atlassian.com`.Maybe the used Java version is too old and can't handle SNI.

Answer (score 1):

This was related to the Java version. Updating from JDK 11.0.2 to JDK 11.0.4 solved the issue.